# Getting TimeoutException when I run my tests in background

Tags: java, selenium

I have written a script in Java Selenium which works perfectly fine when the chrome browser is running on foreground. But when browser is kept in background while the script is running, I get `org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of Proxy element for` even though that element is present on the UI. I also wait for complete page load by using below code but still no luck.

```
public void waitForPageToLoad() {
    try {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 30);
        ExpectedCondition<Boolean> jsLoad = driver -> ((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript("return document.readyState")
                .toString().equals("complete");
        wait.until(jsLoad);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Not able to get the reason why there is no error on foreground but only in background. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to run the program in headless mode? Ideally it should not throw any error if running as headless

Comment: @AdarshKumarGM I am not using headless. As soon as the chrome browser opens, I will open my text editor and observe the logs. In this case, browser is running behind my text editor.

Comment: Okay, then I suppose your browser is not getting the control, what I mean to say is, when tests are run and it is running in background then I think (not 100% sure), maybe selenium is thinking that browser isn't present or something of such sort. Why don't u use Loggers and allow browsers  to capture, I mean let it run and check logs later ?

Comment: Thank you @AdarshKumarGM but I would like to know the exact reason for this and also get the solution id there are any.